# Paypal payment update MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I was just trying to use the paypal api in order to give some customers a link to pay, they pay and it updates stuff from a db I have. See, problem there is that I dont know how to code in PHP (yet), and I dont really understand how the resources I've found on the internet work. At least not enough to be able to modify them to my liking.

What the end result I am hoping a system where I can just do something like mydomain.com/file.php?id=21321321312&amount=20 and from then that makes it so that people pay up using paypal, and it grabs from a sql db the previus balance and adds a formula (like "2 * amount") to that already existing balance, and updates the row.

Can someone help me either understand how to modify already existing code out there to do whats above, or point me to a tutorial if this sorta thing is already made.

Comment: Would you please identify your problem better and ask a question? We need to make our requests in question form. Examples are already given in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/sandbox/

Answer (score 0):

So... if you let the browser hit a page with that type of exposed information, anyone can fill your database with fake purchases just by changing the id and amount. Generally, when someone submits a payment through your site with a service like PayPal, the whole transaction happens in a window or dialog that PayPal controls. At the end of it, the JavaScript for PayPal will return some highly random PayPal transaction id... And that's what you send to your php backend code. Then in php you call the PayPal API, check if the transaction went through and how much it was for (hopefully the right amount) and THEN you store all of that in your database and award the purchased product to the customer.

So the order is: Let PayPal run its front end JavaScript and take the resulting code they send you, pass that code to your backend, and then all within the backend check the code against PayPal and record it to the database.